# Nginx $cache_key with optional $arg

Tags: nginx

I want to create a $cache_key that neglects all query parameters but one special (if present) that I use for versioning .css and .js files.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/script.js?build=123">
```

When I deploy, with a new version nr, the above line will read

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/script.js?build=124">
```

What I want is to enforce Nginx to cache based on the optional occurence of 'build' but neglect any other query params for calculating the $cache_key.

Ex:

```
Path         Cache as
/a           /a
/a?build=1   /a?1
/a?build=2   /a?2
/a?robot1=x  /a
/a?robot2=y  /a
/a?          /a
```

I have tried:

```
set $cache_key "$uri$is_args$arg_build"
```

but I can't get it to work. (Behaves like you would expect of "$uri$args")

**UPDATE**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  domain.se;
    client_max_body_size 20M;
    location / {
        rewrite  ^/(.*)$  /$1  break;
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Protocol http;
        proxy_read_timeout 480;
        proxy_connect_timeout 480;
        proxy_cache_key "$uri$is_args$arg_build";
        proxy_cache my-cache;
        proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control;
        proxy_cache_valid  200 302  1m;
        proxy_cache_valid  404      30s;
        proxy_cache_methods GET;
        add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
    }
}
```

Seemed like I had forgotten the proxy_cache_key. Above config works.

Comment: What are caching directives? And better put full config.

Comment: Thanks @AlexeyTen for making me go through config again.

Comment: I would replace `$is_args` with `?`. In that case you will not get different cache keys for `/a` and `/a?x=1`

Comment: Thanks! Lowered my load even more.